# Triggering buttons in contained iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an HTML + javascript page that embeds a page in an iframe. I would like to be able to trigger a submit button (which causes a POST) within the embedded page using javascript in the enclosing page. Is there a library already doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `IFRAME` hosts a page in the same domain, you can say

```
// To trigger from the enclosing page
var yourFrame = document.getElementById("iframeId");
if(yourFrame.contentDocument) {    
   yourFrame.contentDocument.getElementById("formId").submit(); // FF, etc
} else {
   yourFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementById("formId").submit(); // IE
}

// To trigger from the enclosed page
document.getElementById("formId").submit();
```

... where `iframeId` is the ID of the iframe, and `formId` is the ID of the form inside the iframe, something like

Inside the document:

```
<iframe id="iframeId" src="/somePage.html" ... >
```

Inside the document at "`somePage.html`":

```
<form id="formId" method="post" action="...">
```

Note that if the `IFRAME` is hosting a page in another domain, then if you try to submit from the enclosing page, you will probably get some kind of "access denied" error.  This is a security precaution taken by the browser to prevent malicious scripting (e.g. to prevent things like automatically submitting a form on a user's behalf)

Comment: @George: You're absolutely correct; thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1):

The `iframe` needs to be in the same domain, otherwise you are SOL.

To access the elements in the frame, you need to behave differently in different browsers.

First, get the frame:

- `document.getElementById` always works.
- `window.frames[ frameName ]` should be fine too, but use the first one

Then get the document (here's where it gets tricky):

```
var doc = yourFrame.contentDocument ? yourFrame.contentDocument : yourFrame.contentWindow.document
```

Standards browsers require the use of `contentDocument`; IE (at least before 8) uses `contentWindow.document` to get the document.

Finally, you can grab the form and submit it.

```
doc.getElementById('yourForm').submit()
```

Comment: being X-Browser is always handy